# Read new data into pointer parameters inside a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I'm creating a program which allow users' to enter planet data. In this function, I should have 3 pointer parameter, so I can pass the address of the variables declared outside the function to the pointers, then use scanf to read data into these addresses (in the form of the pointer parameters).

The program compiles, but the program crashes when I input the new planet data:(

```
void new_planet_data(double *temp_mass, double *temp_radius,    double * temp_density)
{


    printf("Enter the planet's mass (earth = 5.9736e24): ");
    scanf("%lf",&temp_mass);

    printf("Enter the planet's radius (earth = 6.37101e6): ");
    scanf("%lf",&temp_radius);

    printf("Enter the air density (earth = 1.2):");
    scanf("%lf",&temp_density);

    planet_mass = *temp_mass;

    planet_radius = *temp_radius;

    planet_density = *temp_density;


}
```

Comment: So have you tried to run your program in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The `temp_x`  variables are already pointers, so no need to use the `&` operator in `scanf`.